# How to decompose entropy into linear and non-linear components?

Tags: correlation, entropy, information-theory, nonlinear, mutual-information

**Mutual information** is the entropy between two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, based on their probabilities. It captures both the linear and non-linear interactions between $X$ and $Y$, whereas **correlation** can only capture the linear component.

How can the interactions mutual information picks up be segregated into the linear and non-linear interactions. For example a result that says 40% of the estimated MI is linear, and 60% is non-linear?

For well-known distributions, there is an identity formula that equates MI to correlation, so could we just subtract MI from correlation to uncover the non-linear component, then divide by the sum of MI and correlation to get its percentage mix? How about for empirical distributions where such a formula doesn't exist?

Comment: Does this help:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01591.pdf ?

Comment: the article describes how to decompose into redundant entropy and synergistic entropy, not about decomposing into linear and non-linear dependencies